# Cannot set Graphics.SmoothingMode when printing page with PrintDocument

Tags: c#, pdf, printdocument

I am using a PrintDocument to print a PDF and I noticed that the quality of the graphics is very poor (see images). Thus I tried to set the SmoothingMode of the Graphics object to AntiAlias, but when stepping through in debug, the SmoothingMode never changes from None. I am very new to the Graphics object so I was wondering if anyone might know why I cannot set the smoothing mode? Or why the smoothing mode is defaulted to None?

Images:

[Generated with my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FM68.jpg)

[Generated with Adobe Acrobat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfbg2.jpg)

Code:

```
printDocument = new PrintDocument();
printDocument.PrintPage += OnPrintPage;

private void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; //<-- Doesn't do anything

   // Print document
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether it would be the print driver or Windows that prevents you from setting the mode, but it doesn't surprise me that you can't. Printing in general most often involves devices for which anti-aliasing doesn't make any sense, because the device itself doesn't support shaded output required to anti-alias. One question you might look into is whether different PDF drivers behave the same way; anti-aliasing does make sense, to some extent, for printing to PDF, and maybe one driver supports it while another does not. What driver _are_ you using?

Comment: Note that as is often the case when dealing with printing, if the driver doesn't support a specific feature, you can often work-around that by rendering to a bitmap first, where you have complete control over the pixels, and then printing the bitmap. Of course, for the same reasons that such features may be disabled in a print driver, the results of such a work-around may or may not be useful. Dealing with font and resolution issues may benefit, but for something like anti-aliasing, you're ultimately going to run into fundamental printer mechanics issues (but one hopes not for PDF).

Comment: I see, I will try rendering to bitmap first and see if that changes anything. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You MUST place the SmoothingMode first:

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.DrawString/DrawImage
```

You do the actions with the Graphics after. I have the same problem with loading PDF directly.

My current solution is to load the PDF file, convert it to TIFF and display the TIFF frames in the print preview, which is my case.